# multiple-value selection.Text() in single-value context

Tags: go

I am getting below error while compiling

multiple-value selection.Text() in single-value context

```
var selection *agouti.Selection
s1 := a.page.FirstByXPath(`//*[@id="name"]`)
selection = s1
tmp_address = selection.Text() // Error is occurring at this Line.
```

Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: Compiling exactly what? Please put an effort when asking a question. And aim to create a smallest possible example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: while compling check_name.go file , in which I have written the  above code.

Comment: `temp_address, _ := selection.Text()`

Comment: This worked. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The `*agouti.Selection` method `Text()` returns a `(string, error)`. See here in the source code: https://github.com/sclevine/agouti/blob/dab7b01f206e43278618a7e0f5bc3ea39e48445a/selection_properties.go#L10

You need to do:

```
selection, err = s1 tmp_address = selection.Text()
```

If you want to handle the error, or

```
selection, _ = s1 tmp_address = selection.Text()
```

If you wish to ignore it.

Also, if you format your questions in the future properly it will help get better responses.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But I tried this also and found this error --->   
                                                                                                
                                                                                             
                        assignment mismatch: 2 variables but 1 values

Comment: Well, that method _does_ return two variables. So, that error may be coming from somewhere else. Best if you share the full stack trace or spend more time deciphering it, to extract all the relevant parts.

Comment: Are you sharing all the code from your program in the question?

Comment: No, I have not shared the full code, above is only piece of code where I am getting the error.

Comment: If you share the full stack trace or more code I may be able to help you more. I'm guessing the error is coming from somewhere else. It should show a line number at the top that is relevant.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your quick reply.   It is solved.